What makes that day so significant that they can ask Stilgar to call it off?
Chani comforts Paul, who woke up from a bad dream:

Chani: You've been exposed to spice for a long time.
It can create weird dreams. It's a big day. We can ask Stilgar
to call it off.

What makes that day so significant that they can ask Stilgar to call it off?

What makes it a big day is literally answered a few minutes after. Have you tried watching the movie in full before jumping to the internet to ask questions? You're getting downvotes on all of your questions, doesn't this signal something to you?

The user has a history of this, not the first movie they have done this with.

@AndresF. - It suggests that people are downvoting because they see his name, not his questions, some of which are actually pretty interesting.

@Valorum I don't know what it suggests. Since people don't know him personally, any animosity must have been earned by actual actions: his string of very poor quality questions, in barrage style too (like he's watching a movie, he'll ask a flurry of questions instead of finishing the movie first). To be clear, I make sure to upvote his very few interesting questions; unfortunately most must be downvoted.

@AndresF. - The system is geared up to deal with people who post poorly-received questions. Eventually he'll likely come up against an automated warning, then a rate-limit. None of those things are our problem though.

This is a huge day for Paul. He's going to go from being an honoured guest of the Fremen to being an actual proper man.

It must be done today, he told himself.
He thought of the power he wielded in the face of the pogrom — the old
men who sent their sons to him to be trained in the weirding way of
battle, the old men who listened to him now in council and followed
his plans, the men who returned to pay him that highest Fremen
compliment: “Your plan worked, Muad’Dib.”
Yet the meanest and smallest of the Fremen warriors could do a thing
that he had never done. And Paul knew his leadership suffered from the
omnipresent knowledge of this difference between them.
He had not ridden the maker.
Oh, he’d gone up with the others for training trips and raids, but he
had not made his own voyage. Until he did, his world was bounded by
the abilities of others. No true Fremen could permit this. Until he
did this thing himself, even the great southlands — the area some
twenty thumpers beyond the erg — were denied him unless he ordered a
palanquin and rode like a Reverend Mother or one of the sick and
wounded.
Dune

Chani is pointing out that the Fremen traditions don't seem to require him to do this thing today, despite the preparations. If he's feeling unwell, he can evidently take a raincheck and do it another time without causing any harm to his reputation. Better he gets it right than mucks it up (or dies) because of Spice hallucinations.

For the record, when you take a raincheck on Arrakis, the answer is always "No".
